# Krull dimension and Hausdorff dimension

Tags: measure-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be an irreducible algebraic variety over $\bf{C}$. Then the Krull dimension of the associated coordinate ring, its dimension as a topological space with the Zariski topology, and its Morley degree from model theory all coincide.

What about the Hausdorff dimension? For simplicity assume that $V \subseteq \bf{C}^n$ is the set of common zeroes of polynomials in a prime ideal of height $k$. If we embed $V$ naturally in $\bf{R}^{2n}$, it is very reasonable to assume that it will have Hausdorff dimension $2n - 2k$. How to prove this?

[I am admittedly not very familiar with the language of schemes, so I will appreciate an answer which is as elementary as possible - if such an answer exists]

Comment: As $V$ splits up into the union of differentiable manifolds of dimensions $0,1,\ldots,2(n-k)$ then it must have Hausdorff dimension $2(n-k)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This looks also very reasonable but I do not know how to prove it. I suppose I need to study more to understand a complete solution.